# UPDATE query on php laravel not working, fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-update

I'm writing code for a server, and one of the functions that I have to do has to Update all of the fields of a table (usuarios) of the user with a certain Id. The delete and select functions work perfectly, but this one seems to not work at all. The error is  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in...

I tried to make a smaller function that updates, thinking that maybe the reason it was failing was because of how many arguments I was giving it. However, no change in results

```
function update($request, $response, $args){
    $db = $this->db;
    $query = "UPDATE usuario set IdRh = ". $args['idRh'].", IdEps =".$args ['IdEps'].", IdTipoDeDocumento =".$args['IdTipoDeDocumento'].", NroDeDocumento=".$args['NroDeDocumento'].", Nombre=".$args['Nombre'].", Apellido=".$args['Apellido'].",TelefonoFijo=".$args['TelefonoFijo'].", Celular=".$args['Celular'].", Email = ".$args['Email'].", Direccion =".$args['Direccion'].", Contrasena=".$args['Contrasena'].", FechaDeNacimiento =".$args['FechaDeNacimiento']." where id=". $args['id'].""; 
    $result = $db->query($query);
    return $response->withJson(
        [
            "status" => 101,
            "data" => $result->fetchAll(),
            "message" => "Usuario de Id: " .$args['id']. " ha sido actualizado.",
        ], 200
    );
}

$app->get('/usuariou/{id}/{IdRh}/{IdEps}/{IdTipoDeDocumento}/{NroDeDocumento}/{Nombre}/{Apellido}/{TelefonoFijo}/{Celular}/{Email}/{Direccion}/{Contrasena}/{FechaDeNacimiento}', "UsuarioController:update");
```

I just want to update the fields and get rid of the error quickly.

Answer (score 1):

On mobile so forgive grammatical errors 
Let’s start of with your function and assuming you’re on laravel 5+

```
Public function update(Request $request, $args){
   //...code
 }
```

It seems like you’re not calling the request to actually pass any data so we need to call the Request method along with request variable .

Second you should make a model with you’re desired database table so it would look like This.

```
Public function update(Request $request, $args){
   $data = $request->all();
   $query = Usario::update([
   ‘Value_1’ => $data[‘value’],
   ]);
   If($query){
   Return response()->json([status" => 101,
        "data" => $result->fetchAll(),
        "message" => "Usuario de Id: " .$args['id']. " ha sido actualizado.",
    ], 200
   }
 }
```

Here we’re passing our values to the update method that’s being called on the model that is created, second issue is when you use fetch all I believe it’s returning a bool value and not any results

So we can try something like this

```
$query = Usario::update([
   ‘Value_1’ => $data[‘value’],
   ])->fetchAll();
```

Also once again on mobile so I tried let me know if you need anymore help and we’ll figure this out in the morning